# PHP DDD how to name entry point method?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, ddd-service

What should be the best practice in php to name an entry point method in a service when following DDD design principles.

Same as class:

```
class GetSinglePerson {
     ...

     public function getSinglePerson($personId)
     {
     }
}
```

Command pattern:

```
class GetSinglePerson {
     ...

     public function execute($personId)
     {
     }
}
```

Adapter pattern:

```
class GetSinglePerson {
     ...

     public function handle($personId)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: Do what works best in your particular setting and in your specific code base.  There is no "best" way to name methods.  Just be consistent.

Comment: In the first example it will act as a constructor (if there is no __construct) and execute when instantiated.

Comment: Maybe this: `class PersonService { public function getPersonById($personId) { ... } }`

Answer (score 4):

Some remarks that won't fit in a comment ;)

- DDD is [not an architecture](https://blog.onehundredacorns.com/2014/10/13/ddd-is-not-architecture/)
- Naming a class with a verb (`GetSinglePerson`) instead of a noun is uncommon in OO, DDD included.
- `Execute` is command terminology - `GetX` is usually not a command but a query - see [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).
- One-method services are uncommon, not to mention services named after the only operation they expose. Usually you would group operations together into something with a higher level name like `PersonService`.

Comment: In DDD I believe services must do one thing only.
Ok I changed architecture to design principle. the GetSinglePerson is taking the repository into its constructor and it orchestrate it.

Comment: "In DDD I believe services must do one thing only" - definitely not. They must be cohesive but can have multiple operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you. I would read over the [PSR-1 Basic coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) it has guidelines I wish we all followed. :)

As long as you are consistent, that's what counts.

This paragraph in particular sticks out to me and applies in this question/situation.

> **4.2. Properties**
>
> This guide intentionally avoids any recommendation regarding the use
>   of $StudlyCaps, $camelCase, or $under_score property names.
>
> Whatever naming convention is used SHOULD be applied consistently
>   within a reasonable scope. That scope may be vendor-level,
>   package-level, class-level, or method-level.
>
> **4.3. Methods**
>
> Method names MUST be declared in camelCase().

Comment: Ok, but this is not about coding styles, it is more about design principles.

Answer (score 0):

I would use index. If you're using something like laravel or codeigniter it should do the routing like /GetSinglePerson/{personId}

```
class GetSinglePerson {
     ...

     public function index($personId)
     {
     }
}
```